# How to change the textField on the Stage from Another MovieClip in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How can I change the textField on the Stage from Another MovieClip in AS3

In the `StatusEvent` (complete) handler

```
stage.texfield.text = "test"; //Not Working
this.parent.textfield.text = "test"; //NOt Working
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

How do you place text field on the Stage? You could get reference on the TextField by name.

```
var myTextField: TextField = stage.getChildByName("someName") as TextField;
if(myTextField != null){
    myTextField.text = "New text";
}else{
    trace("Can't find text field on the Stage");
}
```

But you should give it a name, when you are creating it:

```
var newField: TextField = new TextField();
//code for initialisation of the text field
newField.name = "someName";
```

If you create text field in Flash IDE, so It is not on the Stage, give it a name on the scene, and access it:

```
//Give some name for text field on scene in Flash IDE, for example: myText
myText.text = "new Text";
```